# Subsetting Data based on whether one multiple variables are/aren't included in list

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to make two subsets my data if any one of 5 columns (5-10) contains a factor within my list (keep.list) and one where none of the cols contain anything from the keep.list.  Here's where I am so far but can't get it to subset right:

```
test.cols <- c(5:10)
keep.list <- c("dog","cat","mouse","bird")

data.sub.IN <- data.big[which(any(keep.list %in% data.big[test.cols])),]

data.sub.NOT.IN <- data.big[which(any(keep.list !%in% data.big[test.cols])),]
```

I think `which()` and `any()` can help but I might be wrong, and I don't know how to handle to "not included" case, as the usual `!` command isn't working.

Comment: You do not need `which` when using `any` or `%in%` to construct an index. Not that you have a particularly complete example. I would think the `any` would collapse the result to a single value which is not what I understand that you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `apply`:

```
keep <- apply(data.big[test.cols], 1, function(r) any(r %in% keep.list))
data.sub.IN <- data.big[keep, ]
data.sub.NOT.IN <- data.big[!keep, ]
```

`apply` applies a function to each row of the data frame. In this case, for each row, it checks whether any of the items in that row are in `keep.list`.

Comment: Works like a champ. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with @DavidRobinsons's answer, but if you want to keep it in the form it is, you need to move the `!`. To negate `%in%`, you put the `!` before the first part of your logical operator.

```
B <- 1:4
A <- 3:6
A %in% B
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
!A %in% B
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

So for your case:

```
data.sub.NOT.IN <- data.big[which(any(!keep.list %in% data.big[test.cols])),]
```

But, again, in this case using `apply` is a better option, I think.

*EDIT*
Based on @DWin's comment, this may not work (hard to tell without example dataset), you might actually need:

```
data.sub.NOT.IN <- data.big[which(!any(keep.list %in% data.big[test.cols])),]
```

Comment: Didn't return the correct result on the simple test case I constructed.I suppose it would have been nice if avoiding the `apply` could be accomplished but in this case I think you were misled by the OP's lack of understanding.